# Adding the value from the first selection to second selection

Tags: jquery

This is what I'm trying to do.

As you can see there is two selections `sel1` and `sel2`

The `sel1` has two option values. The `sel2` has no option values.

What I want to do is..When I click on the button add the value selected from `sel1` will be added in `sel2` option. How can I do that in jQuery? I have no idea how to do it. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
    <head>    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    </head>    
    <body>

        <select id="sel1">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>    
        </select>

        <input id="clickBtn" type="button" value="Add">

        <select id="sel2"></select>

    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your question properly. It makes it much quicker and easier for others to read, and will mean you get more answers. Also, please include the attempt you have made yourself to solve this issue.

Comment: I need to format it by my self or there is another way to format it automatically.Sorry I'm just a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#clickBtn").click(function(){
  $("#sel2").append($("#sel1 option:selected").clone())
            .val($("#sel1").val());
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback..But how can I selected the new option added.?

Comment: See my update.I think you should read more about jquery document,solve your question by reading document will not take more time than write a question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way to achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#clickBtn').on('click', function(){
        var val = $('#sel1').val();       
        $('#sel2').append('<option>'+val+'</option>').val(val);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mr49j8fu/1/)**

**Reference**

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

[.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback..But how can I selected the new option added.?

Comment: @Najwa I updated my answer, please check the links I gave you for reference